# Losing data from singleton class when changing to another scene

Tags: c++, singleton, cocos2d-x

I have a singleton class named GameManager.

GameManager.h

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

class GameManager : private CCObject
{
public:
    GameManager(void);
    virtual ~GameManager(void);
    virtual bool init(void);
    static GameManager* sharedGameManager(void);

    CC_SYNTHESIZE(CCString*, email, Email);
    CC_SYNTHESIZE(CCString*, nickName, NickName);

    CC_SYNTHESIZE(int, currentGame, CurrentGame);

    CCArray* gamesArray;
};
```

GameManager.cpp

```
#include "GameManager.h"

static GameManager* _sharedGameManager = NULL;

GameManager* GameManager::sharedGameManager(void)
{
    if (!_sharedGameManager)
    {
    _sharedGameManager = new GameManager;
    _sharedGameManager->init();
    }

    return _sharedGameManager;
}

GameManager::GameManager(void)
{

}

GameManager::~GameManager(void)
{
    email->release();
    nickName->release();
    gamesArray->release();
}

bool GameManager::init()
{
    CCLOG("GameManager Created");

    email = CCString::create("");
    email->retain();
    nickName = CCString::create("");
    nickName->retain();

    currentGame = 0;

    gamesArray = CCArray::create();
    gamesArray->retain();

    return true;
}
```

and I create the GameManager in my login page with

```
GameManager::sharedGameManager();
```

the flow of my app goes:

Login.cpp -> GameList.cpp -> GameScreen.cpp

In the login page I store the account email and nickname and also the gamesArray which is created within that page:

```
//store user info to gamemanager
GameManager::sharedGameManager()->setEmail((CCString*) parseOne->objectAtIndex(3));
GameManager::sharedGameManager()->setNickName((CCString*) parseOne->objectAtIndex(7));
GameManager::sharedGameManager()->gamesArray = gameObjectArray;
```

once the user has logged in, the GameList is created using the GameManager info.

so the info from the singleton exists at this point.

the GameList page creates a GameObject for each game in the gamesArray. each GameObject has a child button attached to it which is used to goto the GameScreen and saves that GameObjects id to the GameManager

```
GameManager::sharedGameManager()->setCurrentGame(gameNumber);

CCDirector * pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
CCScene* pScene = GameScreenScene::scene();
pDirector->replaceScene(pScene);
```

Now the weird part, when I get to the GameScreenScene the data from the GameManager is gone, except for the currentGame which is still showing the right values.

I have put in some logs to diagnose the problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

I can read the values right before the GameListScene changes to the GameScreenScene, but once it changes the values are gone.

I also tried reading the data in the GameObject button call, but the data also doesn't exist there also.

I can add more code if it can help figure this out, I just didn't want to flood this if it was something easy.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: If you really want it to be a guaranteed singleton, you should make the constructor private so the only path to construction is the `sharedGameManager()`  method. It might also be helpful to move that _sharedGameManager pointer into the class as a private static member.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but this didn't seem to fix anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not retaining your autorelease objects (i.e, email and name strings) resulting in deletion of its data when it is released. The reason currentGame is still there is that it is an int (not an autorelease pointer).

You can use `CC_SYNTHESIZE_RETAIN` instead of `CC_SYNTHESIZE` to retain these two string to automatically retain them.

Comment: quick question. if i use CC_SYNTHESIZE_RETAIN doe this autorelease?

Comment: No. You have to release it yourself. Just assign NULL in parent object's constructor and CC_SAFE_RELEASE in parent object's destructor (to avoid garbage values and memory leaks). Other than that, it will handle retain/release scenarios by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right,

Constructor of CCObject (maybe Init() function) calls autorelease() and instances which are not attached to scenes automately destroy after one frame even if it is singleton instance.

I think your GameManager class have no reason to inherit from CCObject.